# Prioritizing 4 values based on availability and date excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried to find a solution to this but im stuck:

```
+----+------------+-----+------------+----+------------+-----+------------+
| R1 | Date       | R2  | Date       | R3 | Date       | R4  | Date       |
+----+------------+-----+------------+----+------------+-----+------------+
| BB | 10/11/2011 | Ba2 | 04/05/2016 | WD | 29/01/2019 | IG9 | 18/10/2019 |
+----+------------+-----+------------+----+------------+-----+------------+
```

I have 4 ratings and the associated rating date - I would like to output a final rating based on:

1. The following order of priority: (1) R1, (2) R2, (3) R3 (if they have a value <> "NA" or "NR" or "WD") - since R3 = "WD" it cannot be the result value
2. the most recent date
3. R4 only if R1, R2, R3 do not have a value or are = "NA" or "NR" or "WD" - date does not matter

In this case the result value should be Ba2

I've tried:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"NA",A2<>"NR",B2>D2,B2>F2),A2,IF(AND(C2<>"NA",C2<>"NR",D2>B2,D2>F2),C2,IF(AND(E2<>"NA",E2<>"NR",E2<>"WD",F2>B2,F2>D2),E2,IF(G2<>"#N/A N/A",G2,"No Rating"))))
```

This does not work as it will skip the first value if the date is smaller than another rating and return IG9

Any help on a formula to get me there would be hugley appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59056588/edit) to show us exactly what it is you tried and how it fails to meet the expected goal?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following overall, but i can give a small suggestion... `=if(OR(A2="WD",A2="NR",A2="WD"),0,1)` would allow you to tell if you have one of those values, meaning they are `0`, of no value.  You can then assess `>0` and pull... whatever it is you actually are desiring.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad --edit made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(2:2,,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:F2/((ISERROR(MATCH(A2:E2,{"WD","NA","NR"},0)))*(NOT(ISNUMBER(--A2:E2)))),1),2:2,0)-1),G2)
```

Note the same size but offset ranges.  Also, this only works properly if the dates are unique.

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate this - am I doing something wrong though; im still getting IG9? Is there something specific I need to do when entering the formula?

Comment: No, remove the `IFERROR(...,G2)` leaving on the INDEX and see what error you are getting.

Comment: Also verify that your dates are all true dates and not a string that looks like a date.

Comment: #NUM! Error - does that help?

Comment: There was a space after the WD from copying over - It's working now
Thanks a million for this - Answer Accepted!